# Symbol similar to lesseqqgtr, but with approx instead of the equality

Tags: math-mode, symbols

Is there a ready-to-use symbol, nicely looking command similar to `\lesseqqgtr`, but with `\approx` instead of the `=` symbol?

My current approach is `\underset{>}{\overset{<}{\approx}}`, which looks quite unnatural, with too big spaces between the symbols; and it's also not as wide as `\lesseqqgtr`.

---

**Edit.** Since the `\approx` symbol needs more space than `=` due to its wiggliness, making it hard to make a symbol as compact as `\lesseqqgtr`, something similar to `\lesseqgtr` (`\underset{>}{\overset{<}{\sim}}`) might also work for me.

Comment: Does that actually *mean* anything?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau If the paper defines it, then yes.

Comment: You might also try stacking `\gtrless` on top of `\sim`, see if that looks better to you?

Comment: With the "greater" component on top, I think you mean `\gtreqqless`.

Comment: @corey979 What is the use of this symbol ?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Typo, thanks, fixed. @DonaldArseneau @projetmbc – I understand `\lessgtr` similarly to `\pm` as encoding two cases in one symbol, like _either a<b or a>b_. And since `\lessapprox` and `\gtrapprox` mean _approximately less/greater than_, I intend to use this as _there are two cases to consider: one in which a is approximately less than b, and the other when a is approximately greater than b_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no package.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\lessapproxgtr}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\lagA{<>}}}
\newcommand{\gtrapproxless}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\lagA{><}}}
\newcommand{\lagA}[2]{\lagB#1#2}
\newcommand{\lagB}[3]{%
  \vcenter{\offinterlineskip\mathsurround=0pt
    \halign{##\cr$#1#2$\cr\noalign{\vskip0.5pt}$#1\approx$\cr\noalign{\vskip0.5pt}$#1#3$\cr}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$a \lessapproxgtr b \gtrapproxless c \lesseqqgtr d$
$\scriptstyle a \lessapproxgtr b \gtrapproxless c \lesseqqgtr d$
$\scriptscriptstyle a \lessapproxgtr b \gtrapproxless c \lesseqqgtr d$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Really tricky!

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine} 
\newcommand{\lessapproxgtr}{\setstackgap{L}{1.35ex}\mathrel{\Vectorstack{<\\ \approx \\>}}}

\begin{document}

$a \lessapproxgtr b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sort of, but too stretched vertically compared to the `\lesseqqgtr` symbol: https://imgur.com/SPd1ODu

Comment: Actually, what you have here is "greater approximately less".  Combinations of this sort are read from top to bottom.  To @corey979 -- given the shape of the approx component, there's really no way to make it more compact vertically other than by changing the shapes of the components.

Comment: @barbarabeeton::  What was I thinking? 'Tis fixed now.